# How to fix incorrect angles after stereo rectification in OpenCV?

Tags: java, android, objective-c, opencv, stereo-3d

If I try to rectify an object ( a box). But in virtual 3D world of rectified image i recieve 45 degrees instead of 90. Where I have to change the data to get correct value of the angle?

Comment: java, objective-C, perhaps you can also add the C# tag?

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian No. Just i'm trying to use both planforms - Android and iOS and got the same result.